# how to connect iphone table view to video

Tags: iphone

I am beginner developer of application and need some help;
I just create an application. On the main view there is a table view with Images and relevant text. 
The next step I need to develop is to connect  each cell with separate video. 
Please, help me with this and send me sample code
Thank you in advance
Zaza

Comment: Hi dude, check the spelling while writing. I think the heading itself is a mistake. Please read it before posting. Please keep this in mind next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentations before start doing. The best place I prefer to start learning is developer.apple.com. You will get all you want from the site. Please go through these link:- [tableview user guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html). In the document you will get a section with managing cells> custom cells. Please go through it.